# IE 8 dropdown menu issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

I am having some issues with a css dropdown menu. It works fine in all browsers except IE8 (and possibly other versions of IE).

When you scroll over Instructors or Schedule a dropdown menu appears. In IE it is getting cutoff because it goes outside of top most parent div `#main_menu`. I realized this by setting `overflow:auto` on that div and it created a scrollbar where I could see the rest of the dropdown. I have tried adding `position:absolute` to the dropdown as well as `position:relative` to the dropdown's first parent the `<li>` but that did not seem to help.

The site can be seen here: http://www.yogalivelink.com

Comment: First change I would recommend is set .menu ul.dropdown - margin-top:4px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site is working perfectly in IE7/8 - I don't see issues. Moreover  markup shouldn't be for layout anymore. and when you have dropdowns or modal UI on the page, you should not be using overflow hidden.

If you need overflow:hidden for float clearing purpose, use .clearfix hack

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Clearfix source: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Your `<div class="menu">` has been collapsed by floats so use this class for clearing float out.